# QuickBlox retrieve user´s password return null value

Tags: null, passwords, quickblox

I would like to retrieve user´s password, but I always get null values, Any idea,please?

the code is:

```
public static boolean getUser(  int userId) {
        TAG = "UserService.getUser";
        userId = 195655;
        QBUsers.getUser(userId, new QBCallbackImpl() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Result result) {
                if (result.isSuccess()) {
                     QBUserResult qbUserResult = (QBUserResult) result;
                        Log.d(TAG,"User: "+ qbUserResult.getUser().toString());

                        Log.d(TAG, "Password: "+qbUserResult.getUser().getPassword());

                } else {
                    for (String s : result.getErrors()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "createSession error: " + s);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
```

it happens with all users, I can´t get password values. Do I need to do anything special?

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's OK that you can't retrieve password. Because it's not safe to store it in open form.
Only user know it's own password.

Could you please describe your requirements, why you need access to users passwords?

Comment: sorry, my mistake. I don´t really need it.

thanks for your quick answer.